# How to get all users of a site role in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, user-permissions

I have LDAP imported *user groups* which I have mapped to *site roles* (as mapping them to organization roles was not possible for Liferay 6.1).

So for example I have mapped the user group 'my_site administrators' to the site role 'Site Administrators' of the site 'my_site'.

How can I get *all the users that are members of a site role* taking into account the user group memberships too?

I have tried the following code but did not work.

```
Set<User> siteMembers = new HashSet<User>();
Group group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(layout.getGroupId());
Integer[] types = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(2)}; //site roles
List<Role> siteRoles = RoleLocalServiceUtil.search(group.getCompanyId(), null, types, 0, 10, null);
Set<UserGroupRole> siteUserGroupRoles = new HashSet<UserGroupRole>();

for (Iterator<Role> iterator = siteRoles.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Role siteRole = (Role) iterator.next();
    List<UserGroupRole> userGroupRoles = UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(group.getGroupId(), siteRole.getRoleId());
    siteUserGroupRoles.addAll(userGroupRoles);
}
for (Iterator<UserGroupRole> it1 = siteUserGroupRoles.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
    UserGroupRole userGroupRole = (UserGroupRole) it1.next();
    User userGroupUser = userGroupRole.getUser();
    siteMembers.add(userGroupUser);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the following solution:

```
Set<User> siteMembers = new HashSet<User>();
Group group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(layout.getGroupId());
long groupId = group.getGroupId();
Integer[] types = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(2)}; //site roles
List<Role> siteRoles = RoleLocalServiceUtil.search(group.getCompanyId(), null, types, 0, 10, null);
Set<UserGroupGroupRole> siteUserGroupGroupRoles = new HashSet<UserGroupGroupRole>();

for (Iterator<Role> iterator = siteRoles.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Role siteRole = (Role) iterator.next();
    List<UserGroupGroupRole> userGroupGroupRoles = UserGroupGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(groupId, siteRole.getRoleId());
    siteUserGroupGroupRoles.addAll(userGroupGroupRoles);
}
for (Iterator<UserGroupGroupRole> it1 = siteUserGroupGroupRoles.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
    UserGroupGroupRole userGroupGroupRole = (UserGroupGroupRole) it1.next();
    long userGroupId = userGroupGroupRole.getUserGroupId();
    List<User> userGroupUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupUsers(userGroupId);
    siteMembers.addAll(userGroupUsers);
}
siteMembers.addAll(UserLocalServiceUtil.getGroupUsers(groupId));
```

It does not seem straight-forward. I would expect a method fetching all site members, even the indirect ones through **site role-user group-user** mapping.

I had to fetch separately all users belonging to all user groups having a site role association with the site and on top of that fetch all users with direct membership to the site.

Any other more straight-forward solution would be welcome.

Comment: The only case that is not covered here is the user groups assigned to the site that do not have a site role association. Is there any way to fetch these user groups? I could ask a separate question for this if needed.

Comment: Regarding RoleLocalServiceUtil.search(group.getCompanyId(), null, types, 0, 10, null); it will return only 10 rows?What if there are more than that?

Answer (score 0):

When we associate any site roles to user then association will be stored in UserGroupRole table.When ever we want get site roles then we have to use respective service class to access those roles like we need use UserGroupRoleLocalService.java class there we can find many service methods.

UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),supervisorRole.getRoleId());

And then you can get userId from UserGroupRole object.